# No setter found for property 'kBaseName' in class 'org.kie.spring.factorybeans.KBaseFactoryBean'

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, drools, kie

This is an integration issue of Drools KIE and Spring MVC Web V 3.2.3 where google just isn't finding any references to so I'll try my luck here ...

I'm integrating Drools KIE and Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE (MVC Web)- and I'm getting the following error:

**No setter found for property 'kBaseName' in class 'org.kie.spring.factorybeans.KBaseFactoryBean'**

[config set: maven-spring-drools/web-context application-config.xml
/maven-spring-drools/src/main/resources/spring

The Project is a pure Maven project w/out any outside natures imposed upon it (aka. Drools/Spring).

It's complaining that it can't find the setters for the kBaseName', which is set here:

I'm using a kmodule.xml found in the META-INF dir under the src/main/resources dir.

Can anyone help me discover the disconnect?

Moreover - do I have to do it this way? The project executes the SPring MVC Web App just fine and the Drools KIE test case runs perfectly in the same Maven project. Can't I just integrate them programmatically instead?

Many thanks in advance ... :-)

The offending file: application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">

         <context:component-scan base-package="com.versaggi.springweb"/>  

        <kie:kmodule id="ksession-rules">
           <kie:kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
           </kie:kbase>
        </kie:kmodule>

        <bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

Comment: In corresponding woth mark Proctor (Drools) - He suspects that the current code looks for the different xml, depending on the container. i.e. spring looks for kmodule-spring.xml. Perhaps what is needed is to fallback to kmodule.xml if that is not present. I'll test this out and report my findings ....

Comment: Update: 

The Drools Spring authority has provided a GitHub link with an example (they endorse) illustrating the proper integration of Drools KIE / Spring MVC techniques. 

It can be found here: https://github.com/vinodkiran/kie-springmvc

Comment: Hi ProfVersaggi did you found any solution of the issue. I'm also stuck at this point and the github example has same errors on my machine